# Can the inverse of an element of a countable set approach infinity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say we have a countable set $A$.

$f:\mathbb{N}\to A$.

Can we say that there exists at least one element $a\in A$ such that $f^{-1}(a)$ is greater than any number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we choose. Remember that $a$ is an element we explicitly know.

Comment: do you mean that $f$ is an injection? otherwise what if $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is just reduction modulo $2$?

Comment: $f$ is a bijection. I suppose that forms the definiton for a countable set.

Comment: well, there must be such a bijection, but that is different to $f$ being a witness to the fact that $A$ is countable. do you mean countably infinite? otherwise the example works again when you take $A = \{0, 1\}$

Comment: Yes. Countably infinite. Should have added that. Denumerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approaching infinity does not mean being transfinite. Furthermore, the natural numbers are ordered without a maximum, so being "larger than any other number" means that you're not a natural number.

If we do not require $f$ to be injective, however, it is possible that $f^{-1}(a)$ is an unbounded set of integers. Namely, the following statement is true:$$\newcommand{\textsf}[1]{\mathsf{\text{#1}}}\textsf{For all }{\it n}\textsf{ there exists }{\it m}\textsf{ such that}\colon {\it n<m}\textsf{ and }f(m)=a.$$

In this sense, $f^{-1}(a)$ does "approach" infinity. It is possible, that $f\colon\Bbb N\to A$ is such that *every* $a\in A$ has an infinite preimage. At least, of course, when $A$ is countable.

Comment: But even if the mapping is injective, why can't we have $f^{-1}(a)=m$, where for every finite $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $m>n$? And I said "greater than any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we choose". We can ony choose finite members of $\mathbb{N}$. Hence the implication is we've chosen an infinite member of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: These might sound like terribly stupid questions, which I'm sure they are, but they've been conceptually troubling me for some time now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: If $f$ is injective then $f^{-1}(a)$ is a single number $m$. Numbers are constant. Constants approach nothing. Furthermore, if $m$ is a natural number, so is $m+1$ and $m<m+1$. What bothers you, it seems to me, is that for every natural number $m$ there are only finitely many smaller numbers, but yet there are infinitely many natural numbers.

Comment: Say we have a set of elements $\{a,a_{1},\dots b\}$. This set is countable, and there are an infinite number of elements between $a$ and $b$. The mapping is done this way: $1\to a, 2\to a_{1}\dots$. Then won't $f^{-1}(b)$ be an infinite natural number?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: If there are infinitely many numbers between $a$ and $b$, then no. $b$ is not even in the range of the function. If you claim it is, please show me a proof (and just saying "we define it to be" is inconsistent with the way you have defined the function before), but you can't prove that because it's false.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: The point is that as far as linear orders go, the natural numbers have the "smallest one" possible for an infinite set (and in particular countably infinite). Sure, you can have a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Q$, but that bijection is not order preserving, at all. The way you think about it, you either get that $f$ is not onto, or that $b$ appears in that sequence before some $a_k$ (that is, there is some $m<n$ such that $f(m)=b$ and $f(n)=a_k$).

Comment: I don't like the chat system here. If you wish to continue this discussion, then the comments section is fine.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've begun to fathom the explanations now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}(a)$ is just a natural number, say $m$, because the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}$. That is, $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(m) = a$. But then $m+1 > m$, and in fact there are only finitely many numbers below $m$, so it's very much not the case that $f^{-1}(a)$ is greater than any natural number we choose.

Slogan: "if a number is greater than every natural number, then it isn't a natural number".

However, if you'd asked if $f^{-1}(a)$ can be made arbitrarily large by varying $a$, then this is true: for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n) \in A$ and then $f^{-1}(f(n)) = n$. We can make $n$ as large as we like.

Comment: Suppose the denumerable set under consideration is $\mathbb{Q}$. We know that it's countable by Cantor's diagonal proof. Say we randomly select $r\in\mathbb{Q}$. It has an inverse in $\mathbb{N}$. Let it be $m$. Can't $m$ be an infinitely big natural number? I take $\mathbb{Q}$ because the mapping isn't done by magnitude: it's not like if $n\in\mathbb{N}\to b$, then $n+1\to b_{1}$, where $b_{1}>b$. Hence, any random point $\in\mathbb{Q}$ can have a very large inverse.

Comment: No; besides, "an infinitely big natural number" is not a natural number. Go back to your notes/book and look at the definition of functions, inverses and $\mathbb{N}$ to see why this is the case.

Comment: It would be exceptionally kind of you if you could maybe elaborate that a little. I have no such notes, and I'm not finding a lot of useful texts or internet links. Thanks! A helpful link would also do.

Comment: Where are you learning about countability if you have no notes or books on (say) functions? A good book to set you off is [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1439835985/).

Answer (score 0):

It exists. Let $f: \Bbb N \to A$ such that $f(\Bbb N)=a$. Then for any $n \in \Bbb N$, there exists an element $m$ of $\Bbb N=f^{-1}(a)$ such that $m > n$.

In general, I'm sorry to say No.

> For example, $f$ is an injection. Then $f^{-1}(a) \in \Bbb N$. It cannot be greater any element of $\Bbb N$.